# efficient re-compress method (at highest compression rate) compress existing file at better compression

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

We have lots of  gz (single file) and  tar.gz (compressed folders) on different folders
most of them compress at -5 or -9. i was thinking to re-compress with highest compression -11, what is the best solution ( we are limited in storage space but have plenty of cpu power)

I tried to extracting all gz files in a folder but we dont have enough free space to do it
what is the best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do one gz file at a time.

Comment: we have thousands of files

Comment: Write a script. Have it do one gz file at a time.